# Импорт экспорт модулей в PHP как в JS

Tags: php, javascript, импорт, export, alias

Всем привет!
В JS есть очень удобная фича для организации кода - модули.
То есть разбиение блоков кода по отдельным файлам с возможностью импорта/экспорта только отдельных функций или свойств.
В PHP нашёл - require, require once, но проблема - импортируется весь файл целиком.
Можно как-то ограничить список функций при импорте? Только путём ООП - областями видимости?

И второй вопрос - как задать новые значения импортируемым переменным?
По такому принципу:

```
import {food as menu} from './menu';
```

И далее food переменной у нас нет, но есть переменная меню, которая подтаскивает значения из другого файла.

Comment: В PHP require может отдать объект или строку через return, т.е делаете return new MyClass(), определенный в этом файле. Части файла не думаю что можно так возвращать.(http://php.net/manual/ru/function.return.php)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать spl_autoload_register() вместо require.
Используйте namespace, use.